# Quote Id returns null in extension controller

Tags: controller-extension, standardcontroller, quote, id, quotelineitem

**Controller :**

```
public with sharing class QLICustomerPricing{
Quote qte;
    public QLICustomerPricing(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.qte = (Quote)controller.getRecord();
        System.debug('quoteid>>>' +this.qte);
    }

    public PageReference CustomerPricingAdd(){
        Quote q = [Select AccountID, OpportunityId from Quote where id=: this.qte.id];
        pagereference p=new pagereference('/apex/QLICustomerPricing'); 
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p; 
    }
}
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="QLICustomerPricing" action="{!CustomerPricingAdd}">
</apex:page>
```

> **(Quote)controller.getRecord()** --> returns *Quote{}* null value

I have overwritten this visualforce page in ***Add Line Item*** Standard button available in  ***QuoteLineItem***

Where am going wrong? How can I get the Quote Id in extension controller??

Suggestions please

Comment: How are you invoking the VF page? Or how are you testing the VF page? I see no problem in the code and you should get the ID just fine.

Comment: on clicking the standard page Add Line Item Standard button available in QuoteLineItem I am testing VF page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a below Page a Quote Id as a Parameter.

```
Pagereference p=new pagereference('/apex/QLICustomerPricing?Id='+this.qte.Id);
```

By doing this, valid quote it will be given to Quote Record inside constructor.

Comment: I am getting Id in constructor but the page keeps on loading...what might be the problem??

Comment: It is because, you are calling CustomerPricingAdd() method inside action of the VF page. If you remove action attribute, then only constructor will get executed.